# How to serve an external website with some changes in content/style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

i'm trying to build a kiosk that allows people to use this [URL](https://www.lottomatica.it/scommesse/avvenimenti) just to print out receipts. So i have to hide the header and other links that allow to exit the page.

This is what i tried until now, without success:

1. An iframe with a JS script that appends css to the page: failing because of CORS policy.
2. Proxy Pass with Apache or NGINX on localhost to bypass the CORS block with the iframe: still trying.
3. PHP with `file_gets_content` + `str_replace`: fixed all the 404 errors but still getting a blank page as result.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.lottomatica.it/scommesse/avvenimenti');
$content = str_replace(
    '</title>',
    '</title><base href="https://www.lottomatica.it/">', 
$content);
$content = str_replace(
    '/etc/',
    'https://www.lottomatica.it/etc/', 
$content);
$content = str_replace(
    '/content/',
    'https://www.lottomatica.it/content/', 
$content);
$content = str_replace(
    '</head>',
    '<style>
        header {
            display: none!important;
        }
    </style>
    </head>', 
$content);
echo $content; ?>
```

I don't need to use a specific technology, just to pull the page content, hide the header and some other sections and serve it on localhost for a Chrome Kiosk App. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use http://api.jquery.com/load/ to just pull a specific element from an external site but it won't bring styles or anything like that. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Forgot to mention you need to use #elementId in the URL to get just that element

Comment: You could do the same with their css url to pull down a copy of their styles...

Comment: @TJBlackman Nice pro tip, I'll have to remember that. Honestly, it's obvious after someone else points it out but that someone was not me.

Comment: lol - it would be better to just inspect the CSS, and copy what you need. Then you can edit it and avoid excess code overhead, but... when you're lazy, just grab everything!

Comment: @AdamH unfortunately it's not working, as i said CORS is blocking these type of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old topic, just wanted to share my experience on that.

Tried different solutions. The first one working was using chrome devtools to inject custom css and js at start. It was working but inefficient and also lead to some random crashes during 6+ hours sessions.

The last working and currently in production solution, also elegant, is using a custom chrome extension that adds specific css/scripts to specific pages and also contains code for custom functions, handlers, updates, auth, etc.

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I do something a bit like this for a podcast feed generation service we use. We post our content to them and they generate all the xml markup for the feed, but I wanted to host the feed on our server and make it look like we did it all.

I'm using Nginx built with the [sub_filter](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module, my location block looks like this:

```
location /podcast {
    sub_filter_types text/xml;
    sub_filter '<atom:link href="http://<provider-url>/path/podcast/'  '<atom:link href="https://my-website.com/podcast/';
    sub_filter '<link>http://<provider-url>/path/</link>' '<link>https://my-website.com/</link>';
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass https://<provider-url>/path/podcast/;
}
```

The other alternative is you could just set up a location block in Nginx which proxied their site unchanged to a url on your server and then point your existing javascript code at that url. Then you'll get the content without the CORS issues, but anyone looking at the console will be able to figure out where the content is coming from if they open that link.